# What does Strunk and White mean for the Strunk and White badge?

Tags: discussion, badges

What is the meaning of 'Strunk and White?' for the silver Strunk and White badge?  I looked strunk up on dictionary.com but found no listing.

Comment: Googling "Strunk & White" (with quotes!) has the answer: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Elements_of_Style

Comment: @Pekka웃 Thanks. Urban dictionary had a definition for strunk, but I didn't think it applied here.

Comment: `Urban dictionary had a definition for strunk` do I dare go look it up, or am I better off without? 

Comment: See also on MSE https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28309/what-does-the-strunk-white-badge-mean

Comment: @ryanyuyu Looks like this is a duplicate to that.

Comment: Going to delete question because of it being a duplicate. Thanks for the info.

Comment: I undeleted it, because we don't have a clean way of linking cross-site duplicates *except* to re-ask and re-answer them, and because I expect you're not the only person who will have or has had this question. Also, I'd already written an answer.

Comment: @Shog9 also, your answer is much better than the existing MSE ones.

Comment: It's a bit like Funk & Wagnalls, but more welcoming:)

Answer (score 50, accepted):

A century ago, a university professor named William Strunk Jr. wrote a little writing guide for his students. Then - as now - communicating effectively via text was something many people struggled with; the guide attempted to provide a few basic hints and tips to help students hone their writing and thus communicate more effectively.

Years later, writer E.B. White - formerly a student of Strunk - revised the book, and republished it. The revised guide became incredibly popular, probably due in part to White's fame as a writer but primarily due to the accessibility of the guide itself, which was (and remains) remarkably easy to read and apply in most work-a-day situations. As the guide became pervasive in American society, it was usually referred to by the names of its authors: "Strunk and White".

In recent years, the book has caught quite a bit of flak from professional writers and linguists. As a *prescriptive* guide, it makes strong recommendations about usage and style that aren't necessarily grounded in either modern or historical usage; it recommends a style that its authors found appealing.

But, the underlying need that the book fulfilled remains with us to this day. You'd be hard put to read Stack Overflow and *not* find someone struggling to communicate in English, whether because English is not their native tongue or simply because they're unpracticed in communicating via the written word *period*. Folks needing help in practical situations, who can benefit most from simple guidelines and a recognizable style to apply, remain a constant presence. Thus, providing assistance in this form is *even more* important today than in the days when Strunk and White were creating their guide.

The name of the badge then is a tribute to this practical idea of helping inexperienced writers, and the editors who make a habit of donating their time and effort to do so.

#### See also: [What does the Strunk & White badge mean?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28309/what-does-the-strunk-white-badge-mean)

Comment: Emphasis on: we don't follow any particular style guide. One notable difference from most style guides: programmers tend to put their punctuation *outside* of quotation marks.

Comment: "whether because English is not their native tongue or simply because they're unpracticed in communicating via the written word *period*" or because they're only practiced in communicating via txtspk, which is not English. Which is maybe the same as "English is not their native tongue", now that I've written it :).